# How to check if the batches are empty in Spark streaming (wordcount with socketTextStream)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I working on simple SparkStreaming wordcount example to to count the number of words in text data received from a data server listening on a TCP socket. 
I would like to check if the batch from streaming source is empty or not before I save the content of every transformation to a text files. Currently, I am using Spark Shell. This is my code

I have tried this code, and it works fine without checking if the batch is empty or not:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)


lines.saveAsTextFiles("/stream_test/testLine.txt")
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
words.saveAsTextFiles("/stream_test/testWords.txt")
val pairs = words.map((_, 1))
pairs.saveAsTextFiles("/stream_test/testPairs.txt")
val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCounts.saveAsTextFiles("/stream_test/testWordsCounts.txt")
wordCounts.print()
ssc.start()
```

I have tried to use `foreachRDD` but it gives me an error  `error: value saveAsTextFiles is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]`

This is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)


lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
 if(!rdd.partitions.isEmpty)
{
lines.saveAsTextFiles("/stream_test/testLine.txt")

val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
words.saveAsTextFiles("/stream_test/testWords.txt")

val pairs = words.map((_, 1))
pairs.saveAsTextFiles("/stream_test/testPairs.txt")

val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCounts.saveAsTextFiles("/stream_test/testWordsCounts.txt")
wordCounts.print()

}
})


ssc.start()

I need to to check if the batch from streaming source is empty or not before I save the content text files. I appreciate your help
```

Comment: This workaround to achieve what i wanted :
 `` lines.foreachRDD{ rdd => if (!rdd.isEmpty) 
{
rdd.saveAsTextFile("/stream_test/testLine.txt")
}} `

Answer (score 0):

I used to do it using following code. I will loop each rdd in stream and then use rdd.count() to judge if a rdd is empty. if all rdds is empty, nothing happened, hope it can help you.

```
kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    if(rdd.count() > 0) {
        // do something
    }
})
```

Comment: Count is not a recommended method to check empty, because it will  trigger a job operation which is a wast in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code snippet to check your streaming batches are empty or not:

```
if(!rdd.partitions.isEmpty)
   rdd.saveAsTextFile(outputDir)
```